# how to disable button for period and repeat that again (javaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is when I click on the button .. the button becomes disabled until a period of 60 seconds has passed ...( like 1min countdown  )
and when that period has passed the button becomes enabled and can be repeat that again

**here is my html**

```
<body id="body1">
    <button id="myButton">Click</button>
        <div id="mydiv" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 200px; font-size: 70px">

    </div>
    <div id="timer" style="text-align: center;  font-size: 70px">

    </div>
</body>
```

**here is my js**

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >
var seconds=60;
var timer;
function myFunction() 
{
    if(seconds < 60) { 
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
    }
    if (seconds >0 ) 
    { 
    seconds--;
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML='close';
    document.getElementById('myButton').style.backgroundColor='red';
    document.getElementById('myButton').setAttribute('disabled');
    } 
    else  {
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML='open';
    document.getElementById('myButton').style.backgroundColor='green';
    document.getElementById('myButton').removeAttribute('disabled');

    }
}
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function()
{
    if(!timer) 
    {
        timer = window.setInterval(function(){myFunction();}, 1000);
        }
} 
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="0:00"; 

</script>
```

Comment: your snippet doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` to disable and enable the button:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn")
function myFunction() {
  btn.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    btn.disabled = false;
    console.log('Button Activated')}, 5000)
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your snippet is not working properly I've made a snippet of my own that demonstrates how you could create a *toggle* which determines if the button can be used or not.

By default the `buttonDisabled` state is `false`. Meaning the button is active. In your `click` handler check if the toggle (`buttonDisabled`) is `false` and only do something when it is. Then change the `buttonDisabled` to true and with the help of a `setTimeout` you can change the value back to `false` to use it again.

Check out the example below.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.js-button');
let buttonDisabled = false;

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (buttonDisabled === false) {
    buttonDisabled = true;
    button.textContent = 'Disabled';
    setTimeout(function() {
      buttonDisabled = false;
      button.textContent = 'Click me';
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="js-button">Click me</button>
```