# How to prevent button click while event still happening? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to find an answer to my question on the web but I didn't come across anything similar.

Is there any way in JavaScript to prevent the same event from triggering two times, while the first trigger doesn't finish all the job?

I have some kind of spinning wheel and I want to prevent the possibility of pressing the button until it turns a full circle, the time it takes to turn a full circle is 2s, but when the first spin is done I want the button to work over and over again in the same way.

Here is my JavaScript code for that event.

```
let num = 0

spin2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  num += 360
  linija.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`
  linija.style.transition = "all 2s"
})
```

Comment: If it is an actual button - then just _disable_ it?

Comment: Use an animation instead of a transition (that's cleaner anyway), and listen to the event of the transition finishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTimeout to do something like that :

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (buttonDisabled === false) {
    // Logic
    num += 360
    linija.style.transform = `rotate(${num}deg)`
    linija.style.transition = "all 2s"
    // Disable button
    buttonDisabled = true;
    button.textContent = 'Disabled';
    setTimeout(function() {
      buttonDisabled = false;
      button.textContent = 'Click me';
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

Also, you should look at this : [how to disable button for period and repeat that again (javaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214165/how-to-disable-button-for-period-and-repeat-that-again-javascript).

Comment: Thanks man, it works great, I don't know how it didn't occur to me to insert a timeout function that change boolean variable in the event.

Answer (score 0):

If the `click` function take some time, you can `disable` the `button` on the `function` start and `enable` it at the end of the `function`.

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const clickHandler = async(e) => {
   e.disabled = true;
   await delay(1000)
   e.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickHandler(this)">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly but i solve this on some other way.